# windows installer upgrade with previous version But not changing dll file

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I have created class library Project. For doing setup i used  VS 2010 to installer.

I Overwrite previous version Using below options.

1. RemovePreviousVersions - True
2. InstallAllUsers - True
3. DetectNewerInstalledVersion - True
4. Version - 4.0.0

But my dll file is not changing. Still it is using before setup dll file.

Let me know any thing i am doing wrong.

Comment: I have found the solution.I did not increment version of C# Application.so when i increment  problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

For more information see:

[File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are a number of links of that page that describe the exact business rules Windows Installer uses to decide how to install / replace files.   From a .NET perspective the AssemblyFileVersion attribute is what is important.  This is what translates to the FileVersion in the version resource.  AssemblyVersion is not important is this is for strong names.